# Why do I need to do this over and over again with my wireless?

Tags: wireless

so after I install ubuntu on my pc I need to do this to make my WiFi working:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then do..
Code:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/
cd MT7630E/
make
sudo make install
```

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300107&page=2 ( post#13 )

I do this and after that my wifi is working,but after two weeks i need do this again..and over and over again..Can someone tell me how to fix this forever?

Comment: Effectively what you're doing is installing driver for your wireless.  Apparently it is not supported by the default kernel, so when kernel upgrade happens, your driver needs to be rebuilt for new kernel version.  This can be automated, of course.  Can you explain your definition of `fix this forever` ? You want to automate these commands or you want something else ?

Comment: The underlying problem is that your hardware maker, MediaTek, refuses to ship the proper drivers in the kernel, and refuses to permit others to do so on their behalf. MediaTek is the company forcing you to compile wireless drivers from source every time. How shoddy of them. Next time, purchase hardware from reputable manufacturers who do ship their drivers in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @user535733 His wireless card is MediaTek, not Broadcom. The Broadcom part of his sequence of commands is needless.

Comment: You should try using `dkms`, as described on the github page. This will, if it works, add the driver to the dkms system which will automatically compile the driver for you each time you upgrade your kernel.

Comment: Thank you guys,yes this is what i want.so when kernel upgrade happens and my driver needs to be rebuilt for new kernel version ,i want this thing  to be done automated,not by myself every time.You said it can be automated.Can you show me the steps please?